# Insert a line break in an atx-style heading in r-markdown

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, docx

I'm struggling with adding line breaks in rmarkdown for a docx export in an atx-style heading. I've managed to add a line break in a normal paragraph but not in a heading

```
###This Heading should have a\newline
new line
```

adds a paragraph.

```
###This Heading should have a\newline new line
```

does nothing.

```
###This Heading should have a  (douple space)
new line
```

adds a line break and a paragraph.

```
###This Heading should habe a\
new line
```

also adds a line break and a paragraph.

```
###This Heading sould habe <br />
new line
```

just does nothing.

Does anyone know how to add a line break to heading in r-markdown?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry: This is a non-answer answer. Or at least a decidedly sub-optimal answer.

The old solution was to terminate the header line with a SPACE and backslash:

```
# this is my \
header
```

which doesn't seem to work any longer.

But it *is* doing *something*. If you render it to HTML and view the resulting source code, you can see the effect (and why it's not producing the *desired* effect):

```
<div id="section" class="section level1">
<h1>this is my<br />
</h1>
<p>header</p>
</div>
```

Other variations (inserting just 
 manually, e.g.) produce similar effects: the break is being inserted, but the second line is appearing in a paragraph of its own.

Rendering to other output formats is, no doubt, producing similar results in those native notations.

The sub-optimal solution would be to hard code it using HTML in your R Markdown:

`<h1>this is my<br>header</h1>`

which results in

```
<h1>
this is my<br>header
</h1>
```